# Add XML File Contents to a dataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, data-binding, datagridview, datatable

So, here's my problem. I am creating one of my first C# applications. It is going to be a type of inventory manager. There's a dataGridView where the data is displayed using Rows and Columns. You can Add, Delete, and Update any row within the dataGridView. You can also save the contents that are in the dataGridView as an XML file. My problem is that I don't know how to load that XML file back into the dataGridView for future editing of the grid?

The data in the rows of the dataGridView are added using a DataTable.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
dataTable.Rows.Add(txtID.Text, txtName.Text);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
```

I only need to get the data for the rows from the XML because the names of the columns are added when the form loads.

Here's what the XML format looks like:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <ID>AN ID</ID>
    <Name>A NAME</Name>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <ID>ANOTHER ID</ID>
    <Name>ANOTHER NAME</Name>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
     <ID>YET ANOTHER ID AND SO ON</ID>
     <Name>YET ANOTHER NAME AND SO ON</Name>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

And I don't know if this matters, but the XML file's name is Contents.xml and it is located in the application's startup location.

I'm not sure if I'm making any sense?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

u can do this by Serialization like

```
   NewDataSet obj = null;
        string DeviceResponse = "";
        DeviceResponse = "<NewDataSet>" +
                "    <Table1>" +
                "      <ID>AN ID</ID>  " +
                "      <Name>A NAME</Name> " +
                "    </Table1> " +
                "    <Table1> " +
                "      <ID>ANOTHER ID</ID> " +
                "      <Name>ANOTHER NAME</Name> " +
                "    </Table1>  " +
                "    <Table1>" +
                "       <ID>YET ANOTHER ID AND SO ON</ID> " +
                "       <Name>YET ANOTHER NAME AND SO ON</Name>" +
                "    </Table1> " +
                "  </NewDataSet> ";
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NewDataSet));
            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(DeviceResponse))
            {
                obj = (NewDataSet)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        //if Successful

        string id = obj.Table1[0].ID;
```

and your NewDataSet Class is

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "NewDataSet", Namespace = "")]
public class NewDataSet
{
   [XmlElement("Table1")]
    public List<Table1> Table1{get; set;}
}


public class Table1
{
    public string ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

}
```

don't forget to add Namespace

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string xml = @"<NewDataSet>
                      <Table1>
                        <ID>AN ID</ID>
                        <Name>A NAME</Name>
                      </Table1>
                      <Table1>
                        <ID>ANOTHER ID</ID>
                        <Name>ANOTHER NAME</Name>
                      </Table1>
                      <Table1>
                         <ID>YET ANOTHER ID AND SO ON</ID>
                         <Name>YET ANOTHER NAME AND SO ON</Name>
                        <Bonus>Bonus Column</Bonus>
                      </Table1>
                    </NewDataSet>";

        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        {
            using (MemoryStream mStrm = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)))
            {
                ds.ReadXml(mStrm);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            }
        }
    }
```